# prevent "dotting" a shell to execute it ( exit in a function killing the terminal vs exiting the shell )

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh, ksh

If launching a script with an `exit` statement in it, you have to launch it as a child process.

If you launch it inside the current shell of started with your terminal session (using `. ./<scriptname>` any exit will close the main shell, the one started along your terminal session.

```
die () {
  echo "ERROR: $*. Aborting." >&2
  exit 1
}

[ -s "$1" ] || die "empty file"

echo "this should not be reached if $1 is not a nonempty file"
```

I am aware of this situation. I would like to write something where I prevent the Shell from being run this way:

```
. shell.ksh params
```

If someone were to run it this way it should error out with a message. 
How do I get this done?
Thanks

Comment: Use `return` instead of `exit`. Answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666846/how-do-you-return-to-a-sourced-bash-script), i searched "bash exit from source file" and it was the first result

Comment: Return will continue on the  program. It will come out of the function not the program, I want the script to quit : do proceed any further when it "dies"

Comment: @123, ...but exiting the script is part of `die`'s intent; the problem here is that it's the parent shell, not just the script, exiting.

Comment: Hmm. In bash you can use `return` at the top-level to exit when sourced but not when run, but that doesn't work for ksh.

Comment: (Aside: Yes, this is a duplicate, but I think it adds value to the site even so; I could reasonably see useful search terms that match this but not the question it's duplicative of, which is the whole point of keeping dupes around in the database at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the excellent answer to a related question given by Dennis Williamson](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2687092/14122):

```
#!/bin/ksh

if [ "$_" != "$0" ]; then
  echo "This script may not be sourced" >&2
  return
fi

: ...do other things here...
```

Comment: The only imp thing to bear in mind with this wonderful  soln is it Should precede ANY kind of shell statement . Else its ruins the show