# How return the control to a korn shell script when another one is executed and finished

Tags: shell, unix, activity-finish

I'm trying to execute a unix shell script from a unix shell script (it works) but the problem that I have is, when is executed the 2nd. script, the other one finish and end with all my script, I want to return the control to the main script to continue with my process. let me explain it with code:

Main Script:

```
MySecondScript="/Script/Scrtip2.sh"
. ${MySecondScript}
echo "Process Should continue!"
```

Second Script:

```
echo "Process Executed"
exit 0
```

That's not exactly what my Second script have, but it have some exit's in case that something happen, the issue is that the second script is ending with my main script due is using the exit.

How can I continue with my process once the second script finish?

Comment: See [how do you return to a sourced bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666846/how-do-you-return-to-a-sourced-bash-script)

Comment: Looks like this is what I was looking for!