# How to return the error from a sourced bash script

Tags: bash, return-value

I'm fairly new to bash scripting.  I have 4 nested bash scripts, and i'm having trouble propogating the error from the 4th script appropriately.  eg:

```
script1.sh:
  source script2.sh
  <check for error and display appropriate message>
script2.sh:
  source script3.sh param_1
  <return to script1 on error>
  source script3.sh param_2
  <return to script1 on error>
  source script3.sh param_n
  <return to script1 on error>
script3.sh
  <some processing>
  script4.sh
  echo "this statement is not reached"
  return $?
script4.sh
  <some processing>
  exit $?
```

My requirements are:

1. I need to define an associative array in script1, which is populated in script2 and available in scope of script3.  I think the only way to do this is source script2 and script3
2. script4 is executed not sourced, as this script can also be executed independantly of these parent scripts

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666846/how-do-you-return-to-a-sourced-bash-script) talked about using the return statement to return from a sourced bash script, but as script4 is executed i need to exit.  I don't understand why the exit statement in script4 causes both the original shell and the sub shell to terminate?  Surely it should only exit the sub shell?

Do i need to look at signals and traps?

Thanks for any help

Comment: What you say is correct: an `exit` in a sub-shell should only exit that sub-shell. Perhaps `set -x` in your shell before executing, and study the trace output.

Comment: sourcing a file does not in itself create a subshell, all it does is read and execute the sourced file as if it was in the main script.  `return` returns from the sourced file, and is a special case.  `exit` terminates the process.  Maybe the term "sub-shell" is confusing you?  A sub-shell is a child process executing a copy of the current shell, it is commonly created by placing commands inside parentheses `(    )`.  I don't see any sub-shells in your code.

Comment: Do you use `set -e` anywhere?

Comment: @cdarke isn't script4 being executed in a subshell, precisely because its *not* being sourced?  My understanding is that whenever i execute a shell script it executes using a subshell, unless i source it.  Is that not true?  Thanks

Comment: `source` doesn't create a sub-shell. It's more like an include statement in other languages. In runs the code in the current shell. If you provide some real code then we can explain exactly what is happening.

Comment: @glennjackman  Yes, i do `set -e` at the start of script1 (i read this was good practice), but if i do `set +e` in script3 before it executes script4 i now get the error from script4 returned to scripts3.  Is that appropriate use of the set command?  Are there any gotchas with using that with sourced scripts? Thanks

Comment: `set -e` is only good practice for people who have the bad habit of never checking return codes of any commands they run. You should use it only if you know exactly how it will affect your script. I never use it.

Comment: @crispo, ...re: `set -e`, see [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) -- whether or not it's good practice is a surprisingly contentious debate.

Comment: @crispo:  `script4` will run in a child process (I missed that one) but strictly speaking that is not a subshell.  Subshells inherit all local settings, child processes don't, that is what `export` is for.  So any shell settings will be reset for `script4`, they will not be inherited.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can keep `set -e` enabled if you want. Then you'll have to be more careful about invoking a script where you know the exit status may be non-zero:

```
script3.sh
  <some processing>
  if script4.sh; then
    rc=0
  else
    rc=$?
  fi
  echo "script4 complete"
  return $rc
```

See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-set

IMO, using `set -e` is appropriate if you truly want to abort your program for any error. Here, where you want to `<check for error and display appropriate message>`, that's clearly not the case.

Answer (score 3):

Best practice is to be explicit. If your code is always going to be sourced, and thus `return` will be valid, simply::

```
source foo || return
```

`return` uses the exit status of the immediately prior command as its default value, so there's no need to capture and then pass it through.

---

If you don't know if you'll be sourced or executed, this gets a bit more complicated:

```
source foo || { rc=$?; return "$rc" 2>/dev/null || exit "$rc" }
```