# Returning from a second function in a sourced script

Tags: bash

This question is a variation on questions that have been asked before, e.g. [How to return an error from a sourced bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39773569/how-to-return-the-error-from-a-sourced-bash-script).

What I want, however, is for a sourced function X to call a second function Y, and then return function Y's return code back to the caller.

At the moment, I have got my script working using this pattern:

```sh
function_x() {
  function_y || return $?
}

function_y() {
  return 1
}
```

In practice, however, this leads to lots of return statements all through my code.

Suppose that function Y is in fact a usage function. I then end up with ugly code, that is not very DRY, like this:

```sh
_usage() {
  echo "Usage: $0 [-h] OPTIONS"
  return 0
}

function_a() {
  [ "$1" == "-h" ] && _usage && return 1
  some_other_condition && _usage && return 1
  yet_another_condition && _usage && return 1
  ...
}
```

(My actual code is [here](https://github.com/alexharv074/bash_placebo/blob/master/placebo).)

Is there a clean way, in general, for a function X to call a second function Y and then return Y's return code back to the caller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do anything: the return status of a Bash function or script is the return status of the last command it executed.

So this:

```
function_x() {
  # ...
  function_y || return $?
}
```

Is the same as this:

```
function_x() {
  # ...
  function_y
}
```

The `return` statement doesn't influence the status, so if you want to return the status of a command, just say `return` after it:

```
if [ ... ]; do
  function_y
  return
fi
```

For your last example:

```
[ "$1" == "-h" ] && _usage && return 1
some_other_condition && _usage && return 1
yet_another_condition && _usage && return 1
```

You can avoid the duplication this way:

```
{ [ "$1" == "-h" ] || some_other_condition || yet_another_condition; } && _usage && return 1
```

Comment: I guess the main problem I'm trying to solve is to avoid all the repeated calls to the return statement. Maybe it's just not possible?

Comment: @AlexHarvey: I've added a solution for that to the end of my answer.  By the way, programs run with `-h` to get help should return 0, not 1.

Comment: Oh I see, yes I could do that. Noted about `-h`. Thank you.

Comment: You might want to emphasise the syntax requires that semicolon there. Easy to miss.